# how do i prove that $\sin(\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4)$?

Tags: real-analysis, pi

It's weird that i have not defined the tangent function yet.

how do i prove that $\sin(\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4)$?

I have prove that $\tan:(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a strictly increasing continuous bijection. (Not yet proved that it's a homeomorphism; i think i can show that arctan is concave on $(0,\infty)$)

Anyhow, i have no idea how do prove that $\tan(\pi/4)=1$.. Please help

Comment: What do you know about since and cosine? Do you know that $\sin0=0$? That $\sin\pi/2=1$? Do you know the formula for the sine of a sum or difference?

Comment: Yes I have proved that $\sin0=0$, $\sin\pi/2=1$ and series expansion of sine and cosine functions

Comment: Yes above comment is right. In books such as Apostol, fundamental properties of sine, cosine involves the propery that $cos(y-x) = cos(y)cos(x) + sin(y)sin(x)$ and also the property that $sin(pi/2) = 1. cos(0) = 1 ,cos(pi)=-1 $ Make use of these properties by choosing appropriate values of x and y. First show cos(pi/2) = 0. Then use x = pi/4 , y = pi/2 or something similar.

Comment: What do you mean by "i have not defined tangent function yet"?

Comment: Why not to draw the circle ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Trigonometry is all about triangles. In this case, the triangle is an isosceles right angled triangle. Now, think about sine and cosine in respect of sides of triangle. I think you have found your necessary proof.

**Proof 2:** $\sin \dfrac{\pi}{4}=\cos\bigg(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\bigg)=\cos \dfrac{\pi}{4}$

**Hint 3:** Try to see the symmetry of the graphs of sine and cosine function in the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. By observing the symmetry you can find that the two graphs cut at the mid-point of the given interval so they take the same value at that specific point.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply showing that $\sin(\pi/4)=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}=\cos(\pi/4)$?

Comment: How do i do that..? it's geometrically trivial, but i dunno how to prove it precisely

Comment: If you have $\cos$ and $\sin$ values for $\pi/2$ and you have the half angle formula for $\sin$ and $\cos$, it should not be too hard.