# Simpler Derivation of $\sin \frac{\pi}{4} = \cos \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$,

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, circles, triangles, alternative-proof

As far I've studied the Basic Trigonometry in School, those are below -
$$ \frac{1}{\sin \theta} = \csc \theta$$ $$\frac{1}{\cos \theta} = \sec \theta$$
$$\frac{1}{\tan \theta} = \cot \theta$$

And Angle Relations like -

$$\sin \theta = cos(90 - \theta)$$
$$\tan \theta = \cot (90 - \theta)$$
$$\sec \theta = \csc(90 - \theta)$$

And Vice-versa,

And few Trigonometry ratios,

like - $$\sin ^2 \theta + \cos ^2 \theta = 1$$
$$\sec ^2 \theta - \tan ^2 \theta = 1$$
$$\csc^2 \theta - \cot ^2 \theta = 1$$

Now, to prove -  $\sin \frac{\pi}{4} = \cos \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

I've no clue what's going on, Why Right Angled Triangles have $\pi$ involved in them and What is the relation between a Right Angled Triangle and a Circle (constant ratio of $\frac{ circumference}{diameter}$).

**As far I've understood the question, it says that For a right Angled Triangle, having a angle = $\frac{\pi}{4} = $0.78539 (approx.),


gets the ratio of *Side Opposite to $\theta$ and Hypotenuse*
and the ratio of *Side Adjacent to $\theta$ and Hypotenuse* = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$**

Also, If it is correct, then Can I calculate the Value of $\pi$ without Drawing Circles and measuring the Diameter? (mean fully theoretical way?)

I've found some similar links like this - [real analysis - how do i prove that $\sin(\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4)$? - Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688246/how-do-i-prove-that-sin-pi-4-cos-pi-4)

But the proof was too more advanced for me to Understand

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Consider a right-angled isosceles triangle.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yep, then what? I 've tried that way also, but that didn't work for me

Comment: You are not being consistent. You start by saying that you *know* that $\sin(90^\circ- x)=\cos x$, but then you link an answer that uses the very same formula saying that *it is too advanced*.

Comment: I didn't understand what it said, and it was graphical way to solve @G.Sassatelli

Comment: @G.Sassatelli $$\sin (90 - \theta) = \cos \theta$$ is not same as $$\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \cos \theta$$

Comment: if you have a right isosceles triangle with a leg $a$, then applying Pythagoras $c^2=a^2+a^2=2a^2$, $c=a\sqrt{2}$. On the other hand, sine and cosine of acute angles will be $a/c$.

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and 90 $degrees$ are different, I also checked in Windows Calculator

Comment: @Vasya $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and 90 $degrees$ are different

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha: of course, they are different, $\pi=180°$. What's your point?

Comment: @Vasya you are completely wrong, $\pi$ is irrational and 180 is rational

Comment: Note that $\pi$ radian is equal to $180^\circ$. Just a matter of notations/units.

Comment: @Mythomorphic what are Radians?

Comment: $Sin \frac{\pi}{2}=2Sin\frac{\pi/2}{2}Cos\frac{\pi/2}{2}=2Sin^2\frac{\pi}{4}=2Cos^2\frac{\pi}{4}=1$  ⇒ $Sin\frac{\pi}{4}=Cos\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$

Comment: @sirous From where $\pi$ came?

Comment: $\pi$ is the  circumference of a half circle with unit radius in Radian.

Comment: @sirous What Radian basically is? Is it a Unit?

Comment: $1$ radian is defined as the angle corresponding to an arc with unit length in a unit circle. You should get some research on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian

Comment: So, why is it not necessary to mention that $\sin \frac{\pi}{4} radians = \cos \frac{\pi}{4} radians$? In Mathematics, it's necessary to mention the units? If not, then how you don't get confused? @Mythomorphic

Comment: Radian are often neglected. It is understood if the angle does not have the degree symbol on it, it is an angle in radian.

Comment: @Mythomorphic the trigonometry ratios are made to work as $\sin \theta$ having $\theta$ in degrees, if it does not, then the ratios and the angles won't match. Radians are illusion

Comment: Technically,  $\sin (90 - \theta) = \cos \theta$ is false.  You have to write it as $\sin (90^\circ - \theta) = \cos \theta$. Otherwise the $90$ is treated as $90 \  \color{red}{radians}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way to show this is by definition of **trigonometric circle**.

Notably for an angle of 45 degrees $cos\theta$ is the side of a square with diagonal with length equal to 1 thus it’s equal to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

To better visualize take a look to the following figure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a right triangle with an angle given to be $\pi /4$.

You know that the angle sum of every triangle is $\pi $

With a right angle and an angle of     $\pi /4$ you have counted for $ 3\pi /4$ out of $\pi$. The remaining $\pi /4$ implies that your triangle is an isosceles triangle. Now you have symmetry and the rest is obvious.

Comment: How $\pi$ = 180? Both are different, one is rational and other is irrational

Comment: You are correct \pi is not 180, because one of them is rational and the other one is irrational.. What we say is  $ \pi$  radian is 180 degrees.

Comment: sine ratios are usually taken in degrees, if they won't be taken in degrees then that won't work. So, how one is taken in radians?

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha  Yes, in real world the degree measure is more common. In mathematics they go with Radian which makes some formulas much easier. For example a right angle  is 90 degrees and at the same time it is  $\pi/4$ radians.  Different modes for the same angle.

Answer (score 0):

When you are considering this consider a geometrical proof. 
Consider a $\triangle ABC$ in which $\angle B$ is $90^\circ$ and $AB = BC$.

Now suppose $BC= AB = a$ Then by Pythagoras theorem, $AC = AB^2 + BC^2$ = $a^2+ a^2 = 2a^2$ and thus $AC = a\sqrt2$

Now using the ratio's $sin\frac {\pi}{4}$ = $sin  45^\circ$ = $\frac{BC}{AC}$ = $\frac{a}{a\sqrt2}$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ = $cos\frac{\pi}{4}$.

And you are done.